# How to run an Angular 2 application through a Content Editor webpart on SharePoint 2013?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, sharepoint, typescript

In the past, I was able to develop HTML/CSS/JS solutions by simply having the HTML file pull in the CSS and JS and using a content editor which references the files (hosted in the SiteAssets document library) to load the HTML in.

I've been learning TypeScript for angular which I know is compiled which throws a wrinkle into things which is where I'm running into the problem conceptually. I know Angular has lots of dependencies that I installed with npm.

Comment: Doesn't the TypeScript compile down to pure JavaScript? I'd think you'd be able to use the compiled output (just not the TypeScript input) in your resulting HTML file.

Comment: Yeah, but i have 90+ MBs in the node_modules folder that I'm not really sure what to do with to still allow the app to run. I tried to copy them into Site Assets and I'd just change the path but it gets stuck on the package.json files which is in each folder within node_modules